# What is equivalent of "Target location" in Publish profile of VS2010 in VS2012?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I publish website using FTP and target location something like 121.xxx.xx.xxx/$folder/folder2 in VS2010

How do I translate it into publish settings of VS2012 with FTP which asks for Server , Site , URL .

Answer (score 0):

1. Server: `ftp://121.xxx.xx.xxx`
2. Site Path: `$folder/folder2`
3. Destination Url is optional.